# CreateJS - Why using just the path while creating createjs Bitmap works for Firefox but not for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, createjs, preloadjs

My project is loaded from server. I am using preloadjs to load image and then using it to create a bitmap. After the image is loaded, the bitmap can be created using 
new createjs.Bitmap(path); if using firfox, but the same cannot be used while using Chrome. 
for chrome, we have to use:
new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("idOfTheImage")); // loader is LoadQueue object

Note: The above works for both Chrome and Firefox.

So i want to know why using just the path works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Passing in a string to a Bitmap causes it to make a tag-request to load the image. If it is in the cache, it won't re-request it, but if the image was preloaded using XHR (the default in LoadQueue), it will result in another browser request for the image.

Even if it is cached already, when you pass a string path there will be a slight delay before the image is ready, meaning the Bitmap will not be available for immediate drawing. If you update the stage a little later, it will likely show up in all browsers.

Because of this, you should use the loaded result always. It will ensure that the Bitmap can be drawn immediately after you make it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lanny for answering my question. I am a little clear on this now. But i want to know more about chrome, as in what behaviour difference is there in chrome from that of Firefox behaviour. 
Any idea ?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Could be how the browsers deal with cached requests.